# Hibernate and Mysql results don't match

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I 'm using Hibernate connecting to mysql as database layer, the weird thing is for some reason 
the result sets executed from Hibernate api java code are different from those executed directly from mysql. They are not a part of each other, they just look like no relationship.

Here's the Java code at Dao layer:

```
    int totalPage = 0;
    int reminder = total % pagination.getPageSize();
    if(total == 0){
        totalPage = 1;
        pagination.setTotalPage(totalPage);
    }else{
        totalPage = reminder == 0 ? total / pagination.getPageSize() : (total - reminder) / pagination.getPageSize() + 1;
        pagination.setTotalPage(totalPage);
    }

    pagination.setTotalRows(total);
    pagination.setBeginAndEndPage(total);

    final StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
    queryString.append(" select a.target_id as itemId, a.isFree as isFree, ");
    queryString.append(" ni.fullName as item, nc.fullName as category, a.downloadCount as downloadCounts from( ");
    queryString.append(" select dldc.current_category_id, dldc.target_id, dldc.isFree, ");
    queryString.append(" sum(dldc.counts) as downloadCount from download_log_day_count dldc ");
    queryString.append(" group by dldc.current_category_id, dldc.target_id) as a ");
    queryString.append(" left join item i on a.target_id = i.objectId ");
    queryString.append(" left join name ni on i.nameId = ni.objectId ");
    queryString.append(" left join category c on a.current_category_id = c.objectId ");
    queryString.append(" left join name nc on c.nameId = nc.objectId ");
    queryString.append(" order by downloadCounts desc");

    List<ItemReportVO> reportList = (List<ItemReportVO>)getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback(){

        @Override
        public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em)
                throws PersistenceException {
            SQLQuery query = ((Session)em.getDelegate()).createSQLQuery(queryString.toString());
            query.addScalar("itemId", Hibernate.LONG);
            query.addScalar("isFree", Hibernate.BOOLEAN);
            query.addScalar("item", Hibernate.STRING);
            query.addScalar("category", Hibernate.STRING);
            query.addScalar("downloadCounts", Hibernate.LONG);
            query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ItemReportVO.class));
            int firstResult = (pagination.getCurrentPage()-1) * pagination.getPageSize();
            query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            if(token != null && "all".equals(token)){
                int maxResult = pagination.getPageSize();
                query.setMaxResults( maxResult );
            }else{
                int maxResult = pagination.getPageSize() > Integer.valueOf(token) ? Integer.valueOf(token) : pagination.getPageSize();
                query.setMaxResults( maxResult );
            }
            return query.list();
        }
    });
```

When I set show_sql=true in Hibernate's config file, Hibernate prints the sql query below when Java code runs "return query.list();":

```
    select a.target_id as itemId, a.isFree as isFree,  ni.fullName as item, nc.fullName as category, a.downloadCount as downloadCounts 
from(  
    select dldc.current_category_id, dldc.target_id, dldc.isFree,  sum(dldc.counts) as downloadCount 
    from download_log_day_count dldc  
    group by dldc.current_category_id, dldc.target_id) as a  
left join item i on a.target_id = i.objectId  
left join name ni on i.nameId = ni.objectId  
left join category c on a.current_category_id = c.objectId  
left join name nc on c.nameId = nc.objectId 
order by downloadCounts desc 
limit ?
```

I always consider they should be the same, but it seems they are not, anybody can help me to adjust the java codes?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't expect to see limit keyword in the result query?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will alter your query to apply limit that you coded via API `setMaxResults()`. It should also add `rownum>` for `setFirstResult()` but, in your case, it may be very first query.

You don't have to change anything as Hibernate applies those in database specific and correct way.

Is there any other difference that concerns you?

Comment: Alex, thanks for your quick reply. The difference is the content of the result set, like for item1, downloadCounts is 1 in hibernate java code, but when I run in mysql the downloadCounts may be 5 for item1. They just got different statistics results.

Comment: Paging and group by don't live well together. If you execute your SQL query directly on database without limit, it will count all appropriate rows. But if limit is in place it may not include all rows in counting. Try to wrap your statement in another select and apply max rows to it.